# Google Places SDK returns 2, but status is SUCCESS

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have been using Google Places SDK in my app for over a year now.

Ever since yesterday it starts to return resultCode 2 (which is an error) but with status SUCCESS.

I tried to look into that, my API Key is correct, the application SHA1 is correct, and it did work for the last year I'm using it.

What I did notice was that it only makes the problem when I choose an address with Bld. number, choosing a more vogue address like New York City will work just fine

Here's my code for showing the AutoComplete dialog

```
private void showAutoComplete() {
        if (dialogOperations != null) {
            dialogOperations.toggleProgressBar(true);
        }
        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        try {
            String addressToShow = addressFields.address.getText().toString();
            addressToShow = addressToShow.replaceAll(addressFields.zipcode.getText().toString(), "");
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).zzeq(addressToShow)
                    .setFilter(typeFilter)
                    .build(fragmentActivity);
            fragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
            playServicesAvailable = true;
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {

        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            playServicesAvailable = false;
        }
    }
```

If you have any idea, please help me with that. The app is already on production

Comment: Can you provide a sample query that shows the problem?

Comment: Also, calling unexported methods ("zzeq(addressToShow)") may randomly break when new versions are released.